# How to convert a .wmf format video file to .mp4 or avi. format?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, wmf

I need convert some video files of the format 'wmf' to 'mp4' or 'avi'.

I used the ffmpeg with the command:

```
ffmpeg -i test.wmf test.mp4
```

But when I play the result file in a video player, I found that the result video was missing some frames per 2s.

Then I used the command below to decode the wmf file into some image files.

```
ffmpeg -i test.wmf im%d.jpg
```

I found that there were always 30 invalid images after 30 valid images.

I want to know how to convert it correctly？

Here is my test file: [test1.wmf](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4630517/cvtformat/test1.wmf), [test2.wmf](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4630517/cvtformat/test2.wmf)

Answer (score 0):

You can try building your command using this little gem: http://rodrigopolo.com/ffmpeg/